# Determining XNA Game Lag

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, xna

I'm currently creating a tower defense game using C# & XNA. The games runs fine and smoothly for a while but after playing for a good amount of time (after sufficient enemies/towers/bullets have spawned) the game seems to slow exponentially. Even when all instances are cleared the lag still persists.

At first I thought this might have to do with garbage collection (and perhaps it does) but to test it I wrote destructors to print when an object was collected and everything looks fine (all objects are collected). So I'm curious if anyone has any experience with lag in XNA and the possible causes of it?

EDIT: This is for PC

Comment: Suggestion: A better (overall) question might be -> What can I do to determine where the lag is occurring?  It seems like this could be caused by SO many different things, we would have to see alot of your code to determine the root of the lag problem

Comment: There is far too much code to simply look over. I'm asking more for theoretical solutions or possible causes to lag. Currently there is no networking involved so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to print (to a debug log file or something) a timestamp as you enter and exit your larger subroutines / areas of suspicion.  This way you can see where you're losing that time, and work inwards towards the problem

Comment: Creating a heap dump might help identify the problem, if you get multiple heap dumps and compare them you might be able to see what is sticking around. This link might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975827.aspx

Comment: Is this on the 360, PC or WP7?

Comment: This is being made with the PC in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things that I've used to check out performance.

1) App Hub has a [Performance utility](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/performance_utility) that you can use to help determine what youc an improve.

2) This is a bit old now, but [for the Xbox 360 this document helped me a lot](http://zfs.fzi.de/attachments/article/160/XNA_Optimization.pdf).

Update: also I forgot about [this Gamefest 2010 presentation](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22254).  It also goes over a few things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that garbage collections are impacting performance, one of the best tools you can learn to use is the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273).  This utility allows you to profile the heap allocations performed by your program, so that you can identify which exactly methods are generating garbage.  Remember that a lot of non-obvious things can allocate onto the heap:  concatenating strings, indexing dictionaries with enumeration keys, closures, delegates, etc.  Even a little garbage, generated once per frame at 60+ frames per second, can quickly add up under the right circumstances.

That said, what you've described doesn't sound like a problem with garbage collection to me.  The GC is generally quick enough, even during a complete collection, to only cause a few frames to be dropped -- in other words, you'll notice a minor, annoying jerk every so often, but not a persistent slowdown.

(Caveat: this only applies on the PC, which has a very sophisticated GC compared to other XNA platforms.)

You should try attaching a profiler to your code to identify which methods are taking the longest to complete; if your problem isn't related to GC, this may be informative.  In the past, I've used [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx), although I've had issues with some of their more recent versions.  You can try that one, or you can look around on Google for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Is the game loop time increased ? Add stopwatch's to the start and to the end of the Update loop and the Draw loop. If it is increasing, try to rule out ( move stopwatch.Start() and/or stopwatch.Stop() ) until you find which causes the slow down. If it is not increasing, it's caused by something else.

Try to add this line to the code:

```
SpriteBatch.DrawInt64(Font, GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1000 /* in kilobytes */,
POSITION, Color.White, 0f);
```

( DrawInt64/32 is really useful extension to spritebatch which allows you to draw numbers without generating garbage, available here: http://pastebin.com/pVw66mGy . Alternatively just use DrawString and .ToString() ).

Everytime the number displayed decreases, garbage collection is ran.

Comment: A better way to determine if garbage collections are occurring is to use GC.CollectionCount().  This will allow you to see when each individual generation is collected.  Generation 0 collections are probably not a big deal; generation 1 and 2 collections are much more of a concern when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not forgetting to unhook events are you? in the example below I add 4 sprites to a list, each sprite hooks an event from the game. I then remove a sprite and raise the event.

In this situation all 4 sprites are still active and get their event raised because there is still a reference to them in Game.

just a thought, if you're using events for your game objects you could be leaving them all running still.

```
class Game
{
  public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
  List<Sprite> sprites;

  public Game()
  {
    sprites = new List<Sprite>();
    sprites.Add(new Sprite(this));
    sprites.Add(new Sprite(this));
    sprites.Add(new Sprite(this));
    sprites.Add(new Sprite(this));

    sprites.RemoveAt(0);

    EventHandler temp = SomeEvent;
    if (temp != null)
    {
        temp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Game newProgram = new Game();
  }



  class Sprite
  {
      public Sprite(Game gameReference)
      {
          gameReference.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(gameReference_SomeEvent);
      }

      void gameReference_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("Event");
      }    
  }
```